# How can I remove .php from URL and not working if add .php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want to remove `.php` from my files and if anyone writes `.php` **not working** like this:

```
www.example.com/home.php => www.example.com/home
```

if a user adds `.php` => not working or redirect to `home`

This is my `.htaccess` for URL:

```
RewriteRule ^home$ home.php
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

inside your .htaccess

Comment: Not for all , i want specific URL

Answer (score 0):

You must have apache active `mod_rewrite` module

The .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond% {SCRIPT_FILENAME}! -d
RewriteCond% {SCRIPT_FILENAME}! -f
 
# Rewrite URL requested by the user
# IN: ID-NAME
# Output: example.php? Id = ID
RewriteRule ^ ([0-9] +) \ - ([a-zA-Z0-9 -] *) $ example.php? Id = $ 1
</ IfModule>
```

Regards